Difference between using any one GPT in "Explore GPTs" and normal chatGPT?
What is Difference between using any one GPT in "Explore GPTs" and normal chatGPT?
Below snap shows normal chat of Chat GPT

Below snaps show chat of one of GPTs available in ChatGPT

